# Hide Boom Bar on Push is the cause of the bug Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a strange behaviour when I push detailed View Controller.

[image]

I have such a hierarchy View Controllers, all controllers are configured by default.

[image: View hierarchy]

Only last UIViewController set `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true`

Here is a [test project](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5yFnEzUOYPrOWFyNWJtazlCS2M) in google drive. I have tested XCode 8, iOS 10, Simulator iPhone SE

Thanks for any help!

Comment: you just want to set hide bottom bar when you move to detail view using last row of the tableview  ?

Comment: @Maddyヅヅ Yes, but any row

Comment: you can use didSelectRowAt indexPath for hide the bottom bar

Comment: I know about this, but my question is about black spot in top-right corner of `navigation bar` when I pushed detailed controller. You can see this effect on the gif.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

following snippet may resolve your issue

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

put above code to your `viewDidLoad` of `TableViewController`

if you want `navigationBar` with `isTranslucent = true` you can change the `window` backgroundColor colour as below

```
self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```

Comment: I know that I can just turn isTranslucent off, but I don't want to do it. I want to have Translucent navigation Bar.

Comment: `window?.backgroundColor = .white` solved problem, ty

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with the same bug for a long time and by accident I found strange workaround. The trick is to:

1. set clear backgroundView on the tab bar, that cause to layout the view controllers differently
2. set a new BlurEffect view below first button
3. constraint the blur view to tabBar (UIView)

Before I was using a snapshot of the tabBar and was setting alpha of the tabBar to 0, but that cause unwanted safeLayoutGuide offsets. As this solution does now access any private variables, I hope this is green to go to AppStore (I'm not yet there).

In viewDidLoad of my UITabBarController I set following:

```
tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
let blurView = UIVisualEffectView()
blurView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .systemChromeMaterial)
blurView.frame = tabBar.bounds
blurView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
blurView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
tabBar.insertSubview(blurView, belowSubview: tabBar.subviews.first!)
let leadingConstraint = blurView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tabBar.leadingAnchor, constant: 0)
let trailingConstraint = blurView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tabBar.trailingAnchor, constant: 0)
let topConstraint = blurView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tabBar.topAnchor, constant: 0)
let bottomConstraint = blurView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tabBar.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([leadingConstraint, trailingConstraint, topConstraint, bottomConstraint])
```

or:

```
//Setting background image to empty image to prevent a bug under top right navigation bar corner
tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
//As that turns of the blur effect I am adding a new view imitating the same
let blurView = UIVisualEffectView()
blurView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .systemChromeMaterial)
blurView.frame = tabBar.bounds
blurView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
blurView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
tabBar.insertSubview(blurView, belowSubview: tabBar.subviews.first!)
```